# $x_1, x_2,.., x_n$ are roots of equation: $x=tanx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

For $x_1, x_2,.., x_n$ are roots of equation: $x=\tan x$ and $x_1 < x_2 < \dots <x_n$ Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(x_{{n+1}}-x_n)$$

I supposed working with Lagrance's theorem.. But till now, it's still not enough... Please help me

Comment: Hint: draw the graphs and see what happens.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't worked to me

Comment: See how all the solutions get closer and closer to the asymptotes of $\tan$?

Comment: Could you take it more clearly please.. I still can't get it right ?

Comment: It's not enough to learn a bit Chinese to ask for directions. You need enough Chinese to understand the answer. ;-)

Comment: It's not even close ? What's wrong with you and your language ?

Answer (score 2):

The equation $\tan(x)=x$ has a unique solution in the interval
$((n-\frac12)\pi,(n+\frac12)\pi)$. I'll call that $x_n$. Then
$y_n=x_n-n\pi$ lies between $0$ and $\pi/2$. Then $\tan y_n=\tan x_n>n\pi$
so $y_n\to\pi/2$. It follows that $x_{n+1}-x_n\to\pi$.

Comment: I still can't understand how you prove all of these.. Could you figure out more clearly please ?